# P symbol of probabilities

Tags: symbols

I cannot find this P:

[image]

My `\mathbb{P}` and `\mathcal{P}` are:

[image]

I have found similar questions related to finding specific symbol or some P, but none of them looks for this P or shows a way to look for your specific symbol.

Comment: Hi and welcome. It's most likely `\mathbb{P}` when some font package is loaded. You can (a) look for a list of available fonts in latex and find your P there, or (b) ask the author for the source code in case this is a preprint/lecture note, look for the journal template in case this is a journal paper.

Comment: That looks like the ancient `I\!P` hack we used to use in the 1980s before the AMS fonts were available. If you have that in a PDF and cut and paste the text do you get P or I P ?

Comment: Unless you have very specific reasons to prefer this specific letter (for example, aesthetic preference), I would recommend going with `\mathbb{P}` instead. I would consider `\mathbb{P}` and `\text{I\kern-0.15em P}` to be semantically the same letter with the former having the advantage of being “standard” and thus much easier to achieve.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try this:
[image: IP]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
    I\kern-0.15em P
\end{document}
```

If you want to use it in math mode several times, you may want to create a macro.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\probP}{\text{I\kern-0.15em P}}
\begin{document}
    $\probP(A)=0.5$
\end{document}
```

[image: IP macro]

Comment: +1. Your conjecture is also main guess as to how the character shown in the OP's screenshot was created. I might also play with `I\kern-.2emP`.

Comment: How does this work with text-selection and copying? Just curious...

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. If you mean, copying from PDF file, I don't know, maybe you can try by yourself. But the point is to produce a specific character. See David Carlisle's comment on OP.

Comment: I don't know if it's just a quirk of antialiasing, but the bulge where the serifs overlap is hideous at this scale

Comment: You're right, but it should not, since there's no bulge either on the I or on the P. Probably an issue of antialiasing, as you said. And well, it's just a cheat, not a real typeface.

Answer (score 15):

You can try `dsfont` package and `\mathds{P}` command (mathmode)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\begin{document}
$\mathds{P}(A)=0.75$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is what the fantastic [detexify](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) suggests from [my bad scribble](https://i.imgur.com/kywvLcM.png)

Answer (score 6):

This is s different `\mathbb` alphabet.  I’m not sure which.  The closest free one I’m aware of is the `varbb` alphabet of `newpxmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[varbb]{newpxmath}

\begin{document}
\[ \mathbb{P} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `bb=pazo`, `bb=px` and `bb=mma` options of `mathalpha` are also somewhat close, and easier to combine with a different set of math fonts.  If you are using `unicode-math`, the `\mathbb{P}` of Asana Math is based on the one from Pazo.